# how to find systemexception in xamarin forms and the type or namespace name 'SystemException' could not be found in Xamarin.Forms (PCL)

Tags: xamarin, exception, xamarin.forms, .net-4.5, portable-class-library

the type or namespace name 'SystemException' could not be found in Xamarin.Forms (PCL).it targets .net framework 4.5 and ASP.NET Core 1.0. Is there any alternative way to find the system exceptions in xamarin.forms(PCL).

[image]

Comment: `Exception` is in the `System` namespace.  It would help if you posted the actual code causing the problem

Comment: Does my solution work for you? If yes, can you please accept it (click the ☑️ in the upper left corner of this answer ) so that we can help more people with same problem:).

Answer (score 0):

Xamarin.forms target `.NetStand 2.0` and `.NetStand 2.1`. I just test and you can use `System.SystemException` under these two versions:

```
    try
    {

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {

        if (ex is System.SystemException)
        {

        }
    }
```

`System.SystemException` is also available in `.net framework 4.5` while does not available in .Net Core 1.0.

You can check if it is available in [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.systemexception?view=netstandard-2.0).